# Im not able to add OneLineListItem inside of MDList

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to add text using OneLineListItem from the python module kivymd. When I run my code I only get the scrollview and no text inside the screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would like to get any ideas from anyone. I posted the code here below feel free to look at the code. Hello people I need a solution to my issue. Thanks!!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.list import ThreeLineAvatarListItem, ImageLeftWidget

Window.size = (360, 500)


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A400'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        pass

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(10):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source="soldier.jpg")
            items = ThreeLineAvatarListItem(text="Item " + str(i), secondary_text="Hello World", tertiary_text="Third text")
            items.add_widget(image)
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(items)









#:include firebaseloginscreen.kv
#:import FirebaseLoginScreen firebaseloginscreen.FirebaseLoginScreen
#:import utils kivy.utils
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#FloatLayout:
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FirebaseLoginScreen:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: "heart.png"
        id: firebase_login_screen
        name: "firebase_login_screen"
        size_hint: 1,1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
        web_api_key: "AIaSyCqafRzds38uZDLlKuI"
        primary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#e6e600")#("#EE682A")
        secondary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#060809")
        tertiary_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#434343")

        on_login_success:
            app.user_localId = self.localId
            app.user_idToken = self.idToken
            screen_manager.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.01)
            screen_manager.current = "main_app_screen"
            #screen_manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            print(firebase_login_screen.refresh_token_file)
    Screen:
        name: "main_app_screen"
        NavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    name: "main_app_screen"
                    canvas.before:
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                            source: "3cr_2.png"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'

                        spacing: '0.5dp'
                        MDToolbar:
                            title: "Tools"
                            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                            MDIconButton:
                                icon: 'message'
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "messages"
                                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color


                        MDBottomAppBar:
                            MDToolbar:
                                title: 'Calendar'
                                left_action_items: [['calendar', lambda x: app.calendar()]]
                                mode: 'free-end'
                                icon: 'sword'
                                on_action_button: app.navigation_draw()

                        Widget:


            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    spacing: '8dp'
                    padding: '8dp'
                    MDCard:
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 170,200
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
                        Image:
                            source: 'happydude.jpg'

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'John Doe'
                        font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                        text_color: (241/255,196/255,15/255,0.8)
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'jonh83e@outlook.com'
                        font_style: 'Caption'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                        text_color: (241/255,196/255,15/255,0.8)
                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Profile'
                                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                                text_color: (241/255,196/255,15/255,0.8)
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "profile"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'face-profile-woman'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Upload'
                                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                                text_color: (241/255,196/255,15/255,0.8)
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "upload"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'file-upload'
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Logout'
                                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                                text_color: (241/255,196/255,15/255,0.8)
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'logout'
    Screen:
        id: upload
        name: 'upload'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Lets upload some files'
            halign: 'center'
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Back'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
            on_press: screen_manager.current = 'main_app_screen'

    Screen:
        id: messages
        name: 'messages'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: "Messages Center"
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: 'keyboard-return'
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = "main_app_screen"
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

# Im trying to add it here below:

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: container

            #Widget:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not giving up, I finally found the issue. By default the text color was white, same as the color of the screen. I had to change the color of my text, and to do so I used the parameters ---> OneLineListItem(theme_text_color="Custom",
text_color=(241 / 255, 196 / 255, 15 / 255, 0.8))